# mqtt_client project in CC3100 SDK gives linker errors

Tags: msp430, texas-instruments, code-composer

I am trying to build the mqtt_client project in the CC3100SDK_1.2.0, so that later I can integrate it into the getting_started_with_wlan_station project for further work.

As suggested in the mqtt_client.pdf document, I built the osi_lib.lib and mqtt.a from cc3100-sdk\platform\msp430f5529lp\library_project_ccs.
On building the mqtt_client project, I get multiple linker errors as shown below

```
<Linking>
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<osi_freertos.obj>" specifies small data memory
   model, which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model
   specified in a previous file or on the command line
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<queue.obj>" specifies small data memory model,
   which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model specified in
   a previous file or on the command line
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<tasks.obj>" specifies small data memory model,
   which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model specified in
   a previous file or on the command line
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<port.obj>" specifies small data memory model,
   which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model specified in
   a previous file or on the command line
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<portext.obj>" specifies small data memory model,
   which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model specified in
   a previous file or on the command line
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<heap_3.obj>" specifies small data memory model,
   which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model specified in
   a previous file or on the command line
error #16019-D: file
   "C:/TI/CC3100SDK_1.2.0/cc3100-sdk/platform/msp430f5529lp/library_project_ccs
   /osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib<list.obj>" specifies small data memory model,
   which is not compatible with restricted large data memory model specified in
   a previous file or on the command line
error #10010: errors encountered during linking; "mqtt_client.out" not built
```

I did the build for all of them using the same compiler TIv16.12.0.STS with Output format as eabi(ELF).
I tried changing the linker's File Search Path for the two libraries in the project for something like "{PROJECT_LOC}/../osi_lib/Debug/osi_lib.lib". However it gave some other errors.

I would really appreciate answers to the following questions:

1. Please let me know if I am missing something or if this is a known issue.
2. I am using a free version of Code Composer Studio Version: 6.2.0.00050. Is it even possible to run the mqtt_client project, since the document mentions Code footprint: Uses 44.4 KB of Flash?
3. If its not possible, then is there some other "lighter" and/or open source mqtt client for code composer studio that I could use?